# Can I have a clear slicer button for date slicer only?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a question about applying and clear filters in PowerBI reports.
When it comes to date selection in "between" mode, I've applied advanced filter inside power query editor so that the date slicer always only show up to the most recent sales date instead of all the dates in my calendar table. Which is a very nice feature.

However, when it comes to default state for my dashboard, i want to only show this year's data, but the bookmark will also capture the date slicer, which selected the current available date ranges, and when i make updates on my sales data. The data slicer changes but the default will not adjust for the newly added dates. (I think its because the logic for "between" data slicer is that it selects all the dates between a certain range and it does not work well with bookmarks.

I am wondering is there a way to adjust this issue? Or is there a way to create a button that clears date selection to all available dates for the date slicer only?

Thank you!

[image]

My desired default state is to just select the year to be this year and leave all other filters unselected. I know i can use bookmarks on selected visuals only. However, that solved the issue, but only if no one selects on the date slicer yet. If anyone does, the slicer will not return to the default state, which does not meet my goal. That's why i think it will be a better solution to have a specific clear filter button for the date slicer only.

Comment: This seems more like a software usage question than a coding question. You might try https://superuser.com or a dedicated support forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as your date range slicer is **cleared** when you create the "reset" bookmark then it should work.

If you are setting the date range slicer to the min/max available, then this isn't considered "cleared" and in fact it does have a selection. Suggest you temporarily enable the Slicer header where there is a "clear" (eraser) button. Select that so it is truly cleared (no selection), then disable/hide the Slicer header back to the visual state you are wanting. Then capture your cleared state (reset) bookmark.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think this is a limitation of Power BI that if we use a "between" date slicer, it always apply "on after and on before" filters on the date. And looks like there is no way to bypass this limitation.

Comment: Did you try the answer? The clear slicer button in the slicer header does clear the selection. Have a looksee, add example to the answer.

Comment: Hi Sam, I see it now by adding in a new date slicer instead of modifying the current one. I guess it might be different formatting or something. But thank you very much this solved my problem!